# JavaFX when I do client:run Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method of Unsafe

Tags: java, firebase, javafx, graalvm

I am facing a problem at Run time. it's a JavaFX application.
facing this issue for 3 days now. I tried to figure it out myself. but I didn't found a solution. so that's why I'm posting the question.
The Problem is I run to try to get firestore object it's giving me the below exception.
it's works fine on javafx:run it's only giving on client:run after deploy.
here is the code.

```
try {
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(Singleton.getInstance().getAbsolutePath("service/credentials.json")))
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        this.firestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to connect the firebase.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here is the error I'm facing.

```
Exception in Application start method
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB] Caused by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method of Unsafe
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.util.VMError.unsupportedFeature(VMError.java:87)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldOffset(Unsafe.java:231)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldOffset(Unsafe.java:662)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$5.run(PlatformDependent0.java:282)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:84)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.<clinit>(PlatformDependent0.java:267)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.isAndroid(PlatformDependent.java:289)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:92)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:223)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:210)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.cached(AsciiString.java:1401)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.AsciiString.<clinit>(AsciiString.java:48)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:72)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.<clinit>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:74)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.invokeClassInitializer(ClassInitializationInfo.java:375)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.core.classinitialization.ClassInitializationInfo.initialize(ClassInitializationInfo.java:295)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:37)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelProvider.builderForAddress(NettyChannelProvider.java:23)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:39)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:280)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.access$1600(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:71)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider$1.createSingleChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:210)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool.create(ChannelPool.java:72)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:217)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:200)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:156)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:123)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.spi.v1.GrpcFirestoreRpc.<init>(GrpcFirestoreRpc.java:122)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:90)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreRpcFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:82)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:561)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions.getFirestoreRpc(FirestoreOptions.java:385)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.<init>(FirestoreImpl.java:67)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:73)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreFactory.create(FirestoreOptions.java:66)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:541)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:45)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:29)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient$FirestoreClientService.<init>(FirestoreClient.java:95)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getInstance(FirestoreClient.java:85)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:78)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient.getFirestore(FirestoreClient.java:64)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at org.quiz.service.DataManager.authorize(DataManager.java:24)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at org.quiz.App.start(App.java:24)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:102)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.jni.JNIJavaCallWrappers.jniInvoke_VA_LIST:Ljava_lang_Runnable_2_0002erun_00028_00029V(JNIJavaCallWrappers.java:0)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(WinApplication.java)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
[Wed Apr 07 13:10:02 PKT 2021][INFO] [SUB]      ... 3 more
```

when FirestoreClient.getFirestore(); a method called it is giving me runtime error saying t's unsafe.

how do I avoid it?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320299/micronaut-native-image-grpc-error-when-using-cloud-firestore): there is a GraalVM [issue](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2694) that should be fixed, and also a Netty [fix](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/10428), so maybe you can try using a new Netty version? Easiest for now might be adding `-Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true` after your exe in command line.

Comment: how to add this -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true

Comment: "after your exe in command line", instead of running `mvn client:run`, you can find your executable application, and run it from command line, adding that runtime option, like: `myApp.exe -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true`

Comment: what if I create an apk. then it is there any other way of doing it through the main method or pom file?

Comment: If that works (I haven't tested it), you can add it to the `main()` method in your application class, before `launch(args)`, like `System.setProperty("io.netty.noUnsafe", "true");`, and build again.

Comment: 'by: com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.UnsupportedFeatureError: Unsupported method of Unsafe'

Comment: still not working giving the some error

Comment: should I go for another database? or is there any hope in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230837/discussion-between-syed-sulaiman-and-jose-pereda).